# Fedora: I deleted a log file 32GB big and could not confirm it through "df" command

Tags: fedora, disk-space-utilization, ext4

I am having a disk space problem on the root partition, so I went through unimportant logs and deleted what could be deleted.

One of the files "mysql-slow.log" was 32GB big, but when I deleted it, it never freed a space on the disk. I use `df -h` command to check.

Root partition is formatted ext4.

Thanks,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Linux/Unix world file deletion does not necessarily immediately free the disk space, it merely unlinks the file from file system.

If there are processes having file handles open to file being removed (as is common with syslog daemon, and in MySQL case, that mysql-slow.log), the space is not freed until the holding process is asked to reopen the file handles (HUP, hangup signal), or the process is restarted.

If you don't know what process is actually holding the file open, use `lsof -n | grep filename` or if you want to see what marked-as-deleted-but-still-in-use files are present in system, `lsof -n | grep deleted`

Answer (score 3):

`df` should update after restarting `mysqld` service.